# how to send value of a text box from aspx.cs page to html

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
private string returnSponserName() {
    try {
        string strRtn = "";
        string strQry = "";

        strQry = "SELECT MBR_NM  FROM MBR_MST WHERE MBR_ID='" + Request.Form["SponserId"].ToString() + "'";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = clsdt.getDataTable(strQry);
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0) {

            strRtn = "|" + dt.Rows[0]["MBR_NM"].ToString() + "^";
        }
        return strRtn;
    }
```

Above is the asp page partial code .How to get the value of a single texbox which is returns from  asp page to html page.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Please put more effort into making questions clear and more specific

Comment: I am sending value of the readonly html textbox value from asp.cs page to html page using mention code.I want to know how to get that returned value in html page.I have use onkeyup() on that textbox.

Comment: please post your relevant aspx page's code. also, if i understood correctly, you are retrieving code from an sql database, and you need the text from textbox `id='SponserId'` as an argument for `MBR_ID` ?